# Is there a method for customizing the positioning and size (width AND height) of a scrollbar for any View?

Tags: android, position, height, scrollbar, customization

It seems that every angle I manage to find doesn't end up working in the way I need it to. My goal is to be able to customize the positioning and size of any scrollbar on any view, be it a recyclerview, gridview, or listview. I've tried using layer-list xmls to adjust the height and positioning, a Seekbar turned vertically, as well as trying to create my own scrollbar thumb and track using imageviews.

In terms of the layer-list, it just didn't have an effect on the scrollbar at all. The other two attempts at a solution (using a Seekbar, using individual imageviews) were nearly effective, except I needed the current scrolled position (getScrollY()) to be able to make the scrollbars I made actually accurate instead of just visually being a scrollbar. However, even though getScrollY() is defined for recyclerview, gridview and more, it always returns a 0, so I am unable to get that information (except for scrollviews, perhaps; I believe that's the only view type that properly returns a getScrollY() value).

Is it even possible to customize the scrollbar in this manner? I'd be keen to see references or documentation that can point me in the right direction. It feels like this is generally a non-issue for most developers on Android, or at least in general isn't something many people have asked for.

### Edit

To assist in visualizing what I have and what I desire, here's a screenshot of the scrollbar as it is right now:

[image]

The following image is marked up to show what my intended outcome for this scrollbar would be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Views have the capability for a scrollbar but a lot don't show them by default.

So any View has a whole load of [XML attributes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:scrollIndicators) to customise the appearance, size and position.

But these are useless if not shown.
A lot of ViewGroups sub classes [setWillNotDraw](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setWillNotDraw(boolean)) to be `true` and this removes the capability to draw the built in scrollbars of the View.

So to get any view to show it's built in scrollbars you need to the `setWillNotDraw(false)`

Getting any View to show it's built in scrollbars is Step 1 but again not all Views Calculate automatically the length and position of scroll hence they return 0 for the scroll position.

The View has to implement the following methods and return the appropriate numbers for the scroll position to be correct and things like `getScrollY` to return more than 0

```java
// Length of scrollbar track
    @Override
    protected int computeHorizontalScrollRange() {
        return (int) value;
    }

    // Position from thumb from the left of view
    @Override
    protected int computeHorizontalScrollOffset() {
        return (int) value;
    }

    @Override
    protected int computeVerticalScrollRange() {
        return (int) value;
    }

    @Override
    protected int computeVerticalScrollOffset() {
        return (int) value;
    }
```

Off Course some View sub classes don't use the built in ones but draw there own.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The thing is, I'm not trying to use the default scrollbar, I'm trying to replace the thumb and track with different drawables as well as changing the scrollbar's height and position on the screen. All of the types of Views I'm using have their default scrollbar active and working, but I'm trying to change how large the track and thumb are, and move it all to the right more than it allows with the default (only inset, outside overlay, etc. for scrollbar placement). Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Your question was very vague and you asked about "any" view, so the answer was about "any" views scrollbars, the track width is changeable on the `View` class, placement to the right should be achievable with content padding. The drawables are changeable with things like `setHorizontalScrollbarThumbDrawable`, etc. I think you need to be more specific and give a concrete working example of the View type you want to change and a mock up of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I apologize if the question was vague; I assumed the statement at the beginning "My goal is to be able to customize the positioning and size of any scrollbar on any view, be it a recyclerview, gridview, or listview" along with the description of attempted solutions would be sufficient.

I want to apply a different drawable onto the thumb and track (do this with setVerticalScrollbarThumbDrawable/setVerticalScrollbarTrackDrawable), adjust the height of the scrollbar so that it's about half the size of the view it's scrolling, and then align it to the right side of the parent.

Comment: I added images of the scrollbar, both one as-is and one with some marked-up changes I desire onto it. I hope this helps clarify the problem.